# The initialization of the CRM authentication pipline execution has failed for org Org Name with a sql error: Server: SQl Server Name

Tags: dynamics-crm-2013

I am using CRM Dynamics 2013, updates were performed on the server over the weekend, and when I try and browse the server I get the following error message:

The initialization of the CRM authentication pipeline execution has failed for org crm-mbtgroup.tarsus.co.za with a sql error: Server: sql server name, Exception:  System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Could not find stored procedure 'p_GetCrmUserId'.

This gives me a 404 exception when I try to browse the server, any ideas>

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue, This issue occurred due to Update roll-up for CRM Dynamics not being successfully applied, therefore I dropped all the stored procedures in the MSCRM_Config and then repaired my installation and the installation re-created the procs for me, I restarted all necessary CRM services and everything worked fine again